# Multiplicity of an eigenvalue=number of times it appears on the diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T \in L(V)$ and $\lambda\in F$. Prove that for every basis of $V$ with respect to which T has an upper-triangular matrix, the number of times that $\lambda$ appears on the diagonal of the matrix of T equals the multiplicity of $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue of $T$.

I'm not even too sure how to start this one other than I know that the multiplicity is the dimension of $G(\lambda,T)$ (the generalized eigenspace) which is the dimension of $\text{null}(T-\lambda I)^{\dim V}$.

Comment: The question is unclear.  **Clearly define T, L, and F, G.**  (field of reals?, or different field?).  Write out V is a vector space.  Does the context of the question (from the section, chapter, month of lectures, etc.) assume matrix elements are real or can they be complex?  Are any of the letters noncomplex (group theory/ abstract algebra/ rings)?

Comment: T is a linear map that belongs to L(V) which is the set of all linear maps. F and G in this case refer to the complex elements.